# How can I get a 60 Hz refrigerator to work on a 50 Hz system?

Tags: kitchens, refrigerator

I bought a refrigerator with 4 doors (model #: LMX31985st) in the USA, for use in Europe. I also bought the slow down converter. I'm afraid that the frequency in the USA is 60 hz, and in Europe it is 50 hz. Because of this, the appliance doesn't work. Does the slow down converter regulate the frequency, or could there be something wrong with it?

Answer (score 3):

You face many challenges with this refrigerator.

1. It is a [discontinued model](http://www.lg.com/us/refrigerators/lg-LMX31985ST-french-4-door-refrigerator).
2. It is made for North American electricity.
3. It is made for North American kitchen space.  It will probably be too big for 95% of European kitchens: width, depth, and height.
4. Many European kitchen floors will not be able to hold its empty weight of [324 pounds/147 kg](http://www.lg.com/us/support/products/documents/LMX31985ST%20Environmental%20Declaration.pdf), let alone loading it full of stuff.  Its weight loading is 36 pounds per square foot (empty) which should be okay in most buildings (less than an adult standing on the floor).
5. It will be very expensive to ship.  Probably at least half the price of a new fridge.
6. A **sufficiently** hefty non-switched UPS (uninterruptible power supply) intended for North American power can do the frequency and voltage conversion, but it won't be just any off-the-shelf UPS.  Maybe one like [this](http://www.apc.com/resource/include/techspec_index.cfm?base_sku=SMT2200) for around $900 will do.  Some models allow input range from like 90 V to 250 V.  Most heftier, non-switch-through do the proper frequency conversion.  I looked for awhile but didn't see any less than $750.

Comment: The first and second sentence of (4) would appear to contradict each other.

Comment: @JasperBryant-Greene:  The first sentence relates to total structural loading.  The second is about surface loading.

Comment: I would love to understand this better. Please define "total structural loading" and "surface loading" in this context. Also, I haven't been to Europe, but I'd be surprised if European kitchen floors could not hold 147 kg. That's only the weight of two moderately-large people.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by a "slow down converter", but I've used a transformer in the past, so I could use 110V, 60Hz devices from the USA on 220V, 50Hz power supply in India. Some of these devices ran for years (think cordless phone base units, laptops, etc.), so I'm assuming stuff did convert properly.

Note that there are limits to how safely you can transform power. For instance, the transformers I could buy wouldn't work with anything over a 100W or so draw, so huge appliances such as refrigerators are simply out of the question.

Also, I'm guessing there's going to be some sort of power loss, though I have no idea how to quantify that.

Effectively, you're better off buying something local to the area where you're going to use it, specifically for large appliances.

Comment: Cordless phones and laptops run on DC so the AC frequency would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I just Google'd, "230vac, 50hz to 120vac, 60hz converter" and nothing that would be anywhere near suitable for you was found. There is equipment that can do that, but it would probably cost more than your fridge. Motors are AC frequency sensitive and it's the AC frequency that's the hardest thing to convert. A refrigerator's main component is a motor that runs a compressor.

Answer (score 1):

We brought our 110v 60HZ fridge from the USA to the Netherlands and used our  converter so it was running at 110v but only 50HZ. it has been in service this  way for  10 years till  we finally bought a new one because of high power consumption. The newer ones are much more efficient.

Comment: What converter (make/model) did you use?